# How can we send multiple request from same user in gatling?

Tags: performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

So I had a scenario in which I have to request two different endpoints at the same time from a user for the performance test. How can this be achieved using Gatling?

Comment: See https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/3783